# Nothing gets saved in the file

Tags: java, file, io, jfilechooser

This is the snippet that saves the data entered by the user into the file. This works fine.**i.e it creates the file at the wanted location** but the problem is that the file created is empty. What is the reason for this ?

```
JFileChooser save = new JFileChooser();
    int option = save.showSaveDialog( this );
        if( option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ) {
            try {
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( save.getSelectedFile().getPath() + ".txt") );
                String messageToBeSaved = jTextArea2.getText();
                int lengthOfMessage = messageToBeSaved.length();
                writer.write( messageToBeSaved, 0 , lengthOfMessage );
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame() , "Message saved");
            } catch(Exception exc) {
                System.out.println(exc);
            }
```

If there is anything wrong with this snippet,please tell where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is a buffered writer, you should flush and close it.

Try adding this:

```
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

To be completely correct, you should close your writer in a `finally` block.

**Edit**:  The flush is not really required since close will flush anyways.

Comment: You don't need to flush if you are closing, close will flush.

Comment: Good point, I guess it's force of habit because of having issues before without flushing. Updated the answer and +1'd yours.

Answer (score 1):

You should close the `BufferedWriter` after you have written data to it. That will flush the buffer, and then close it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `close` the `writer`, then the contents of the buffer will be flushed to the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you are not [flushing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#flush%28%29) the stream.

Answer (score 0):

You should call write.close() when you are done.